# How to automate smtp enablement when grafana pod restarted?

Tags: grafana

I'm working on SQL bdc on Kubernetes, I've set up the metrics and alerts in grafana and also enabled the SMTP by changing the ini file.

But now I want to automate this SMTP enablement, whenever the pod is recreated, automatically the ini file should be copied to the newly created pod and restart the grafana.

Not getting an idea how to automate this task

Answer (score 0):

Use env variables. Any config option from `grafana.ini` file has own env variable equivalent. Check Grafana docker image doc for more details.

Comment: using azdata to deploy the bdc,  cant do anything on image level or docker level
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/big-data-cluster/deployment-guidance?view=sql-server-ver15